# SVD definition of pseudoinverse: $A^+ b$ is as close as possible to $y$ in terms of the Euclidean norm $\lVert Ax-b\rVert_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, normed-spaces, svd, pseudoinverse

I am currently studying [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3536467/356308) answer on the **Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse and the Euclidean norm** by the user "Etienne dM". The first point of their answer proceeds as follows:

> Let $x$ be $A^+y$.
>
> 2. Let me begin by the second point.
>    For all $z$, we have:
>    \begin{align}
>    \lVert Az-b \rVert_2^2 &= \lVert Ax-b \rVert_2^2 + \lVert A(z-x) \rVert_2^2 + 2 (z-x)^TA^T(Ax-b)\\
>    & \geq 
>    \lVert Ax-b \rVert_2^2 + 2 (z-x)^TA^T(Ax-b)
>    \end{align}
>    Moreover, because $(AA^+)^T = AA^+$,
>    $$ A^T(Ax-b) = ((AA^+)A)^Tb - A^Tb = 0$$
>    Thus, we prove that for all $z$, $\rVert Az-b \lVert_2^2 \geq\rVert Ax-b \lVert_2^2$, that is to say $A^+b$ is as close as possible to $y$ in term of the Euclidian norm $\lVert Ax-b\rVert_2$.

I realise that $x = A^+ y$, but I don't understand how any of this implies that "$A^+ b$ is as close as possible to $y$ in terms of the Euclidean norm $\lVert Ax-b\rVert_2$". The way I see it is that we have 4 facts:

1. $\lVert Az - b \rVert_2^2 = \lVert Ax - b \rVert_2^2 + \lVert A(z - x) \rVert_2^2 + 2(z - x)^T A^T (Ax - b) \ge \lVert Ax - b \rVert_2^2 + 2(z - x)^T A^T (Ax - b)$;
2. Because $(AA^+)^T = AA^+$, $A^T(Ax - b) = ((AA^+)A)^T b - A^T b = 0$;
3. Singular value decomposition (SVD): $A^+ = VD^+U^T = V \Sigma^+ U^T$;
4. $x = A^+ y$.

Supposedly, these 4 facts together prove that "$A^+ b$ is as close as possible to $y$ in terms of the Euclidean norm $\lVert Ax-b\rVert_2$". However, I do not see how this is so.

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/974358/356308) answer by "Ben Grossmann" is supposed to show something similar. I can see how this answer is *related* to what "Etienne dM" did in their proof, but I do not see how it is the same.

I suspect that I am lacking some assumed, fundamental knowledge that "Etienne dM" had in constructing this proof, and so I am unable to see how these 4 facts combine to prove what is claimed. I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to carefully explain this to me.

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3778534/356308) related question is for the limit definition of pseudoinverse.

Comment: The phrase "$A^+ b$ is as close as possible to $y$ in terms of the Euclidean norm $\lVert Ax-b\rVert_2$" was chosen a little bit unlucky. All that it means is that $A^+b = \arg\min_x \|Ax-b\|_2$, and that is clear from showing $\|Az-b\|_2 \ge \|A(A^+b) - b\|_2$ for all $z$, i.e. point (1).  (It would have been better to say that $A^+b$ is the input for which the function value of $f(x)=Ax$ comes as close as possible to $y$). In any case I do not really see how this question really differs from your previous one, so I will flag it as a duplicate for now.

Comment: @Hyperplane Ahh, phrasing it that way makes a lot more sense. With regards to your next point, the author actually shows that $\rVert Az-b \lVert_2^2 \geq\rVert Ax-b \lVert_2^2$, right?

Comment: Yes, and $x$ is chosen as $x=A^+b$

Comment: @Hyperplane It says that $x = A^+ y$?

Comment: That is a typo then. Typicially linear systems ar written as $Ax=y$ or as $Ax=b$ and sometimes people forget to use the same variable name as in the question.

Comment: @Hyperplane Oh, ok. All of these small things are probably what has ended up confusing me so much. It just wasn't making sense.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed this now as well, the phrase should actually be wither "$A^+b$ is the input for which the function value of $f(x)=Ax$ comes as close as possible to $b$" or "$A^+y$ is the input for which the function value of $f(x)=Ax$ comes as close as possible to $y$". The OP in your first reference even accidentally mixes them both in their answer

Comment: @Hyperplane Something is still missing. We've established that $\rVert Az-b \lVert_2^2 \geq\rVert Ax-b \lVert_2^2$ and $x = A^+ b$, but this still doesn't establish that "$A^+b$ is as close as possible to $y$ in term of the Euclidian norm $\lVert Ax-b\rVert_2$", or whatever corrected version of this we wish to use. Can we have that $z = x = A^+b$? I'm not sure if this would then establish the fact. I mean, with $z = x = A^+b$, I think the proof still won't make sense, but then for a different reason, since we would just be concluding that $\rVert Az-b \lVert_2^2 = \rVert Az-b \lVert_2^2$.

Comment: I'm guessing that I'll have to bounty this. There are so many problems with this proof that it'll probably require a full rewriting to make sense of. Fixing one problem just leads to another problem.

Comment: You are not seeing that $\|Az-y\|_2 \ge \|A(A^+y)-y\|_2\forall z \implies A^+y = \arg\min_x \|Ax-y\|_2$ ? It's pretty much by definition...

Comment: @Hyperplane But $\|Az-y\|_2 \ge \|A(A^+y)-y\|_2\forall z$ is just putting an upper bound on $\|A(A^+y)-y\|_2$. This doesn't really telling us anything about how good of a fit $x = A^+ y$ is, right? And isn't that the objective of this proof?

Comment: The objective is to find the vector $x$ for which $Ax$ is as close as possible to $y$.  And if one can prove that for the choice $x=A^+y$ holds that $\operatorname{dist}_\text{eucl.}(Az, y) \ge \operatorname{dist}_\text{eucl.}(Ax, y)$ for any other vector $z$, then well, you have found your optimum solution in terms of the euclidean distance metric.

Comment: @ThePointer It seems as though that you are having trouble parsing the definition of a "least squares solution." I would say that $x$ is a least squares solution if $z = x$ minimizes $\|Az - y\|$, with is to say that $\|Ax - y\|$ is smaller than or equal to $\|Az - y\|$ for all choices of $z$.  Do you agree with that?

Comment: @BenGrossmann Ahh, phrased that way, it makes perfect sense, since, if $\|Az-y\|_2 \ge \|A(A^+y)-y\|_2\forall z$, then $z = x = A^+y$ is clearly the value of $z$ that minimizes $\|Az-y\|$ (that is, $z = x = A^+y$ is the value of $z$ such that $\|Az-y\|$ is closest to $\|A(A^+y)-y\|$)! Somewhere along the way, I seem to have somehow confused myself about the objective itself: We want the value of $z$ such that $\|Az-y\|$ is as close as possible to $\|A(A^+y)-y\|$.

Comment: @Hyperplane Anyway, thank you both for taking the time to clarify this.

Comment: @ThePointer Missed this comment earlier. Anyway, glad it made sense!